# Analyze and grab link from an html page

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm new from python and I'm having some issue in doing a simple thing.

I've an html page and I want to analyze it and grab some links inside a spcific table.

In bash I'd use lynx --source and with grep/cut I'd have no problem..but in Python I dont know how to do it..

I thought to do something like that:

```
import urllib2

data = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.my_url.com")
```

Doing it I get the whole html page.

Then I thought to do:

```
for line in data.read():
    if "my_links" in line:
        print line
```

But  seems it not working

Comment: use `data.readlines` then you will have atleast html lines with your links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your code issue, this will read character by character. If you do not pass how much data to read.

```
for line in data.read():
```

you could do :

```
line = data.readline()
while(line):
    print line
    line = data.readline()
```

This portion is not exactly an answer but I suggest that you use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html).

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.my_url.com"
data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(data)

all_links = soup.find('a')
# you can look for specific link
```

Comment: +1 for BeautifulSoap. It is often useful to read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 when trying to extract information from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need Xpath for those purpose in general case. 
Examples: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp

Python has beautiful library called `lxml`:
http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use simply `enumerate()`:

```
site=urllib2.urlopen(r'http://www.rom.on.ca/en/join-us/jobs')

for i,j in enumerate(site):
     if "http://www.ontario.ca" in j: #j is the line
         print i+1 #i is the number start from 0 normally in the html code is 1 the first line so add +1

>>620
```